# How to get history on react-router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I having some little issue migrating from React-Router v3 to v4.
in v3 I was able to do this anywhere:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
browserHistory.push('/some/path');
```

How do I achieve this in v4.

I know that I could use, the hoc `withRouter`, react context, or event router props when you are in a Component. but it is not the case for me.

I am looking for the equivalence of [NavigatingOutsideOfComponents](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/ab4552d2ea0ec5c0cf3c534bca654a1af3ea0dec/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md) in v4

Comment: Thanks @Chris, but like I said, I am not in Component.

Comment: @Chris in a utility class, please check https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md, it could have been a redux middlewarere or anything else

Comment: simplest way https://stackoverflow.com/a/53916596/3966458

Comment: I ended up using the BrowserRouter as root component. That way I could use the App component withRouter. Not exactly what you asked for but I have the same requirements and this is sufficient for me.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You just need to have a module that exports a `history` object. Then you would import that object throughout your project.

```js
// history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

export default createBrowserHistory({
  /* pass a configuration object here if needed */
})
```

Then, instead of using one of the built-in routers, you would use the `<Router>` component.

```js
// index.js
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import history from './history'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>
), holder)
```

```js
// some-other-file.js
import history from './history'
history.push('/go-here')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! At the moment, using react-router4, I had to use this import in history.js instead: import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

Comment: It's worked for me when I put history={history} in Route and pass like a props

Comment: we can use withHistory and get history in props rather than creating separate file. this solution didn't work for me with redux.

Comment: Well done, but it's kind of confusing to name the file history, and having the both import 'history' and './history' meaning 2 really different things.

Comment: Import `createHashHistory` if you were using `HashRouter`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this. It took me awhile to realize that the reason this works is that something like BrowserRouter creates its own instance of the history object and will only listen to changes on its own instance. So, by using the same global singleton, between plain old javascript and the components, a programatic update to one will be reflected in the components. Thanks

Comment: Paul S I am trying what you have suggested and it works in the sense that component page changes but window.location is not changing with the new URL. Any clue why it might be happening?

Comment: @cauchy The two potential issues that immediately come to mind are 1) you are creating a memory history instead of a browser history or 2) your app is running in an <iframe>.

Comment: @PaulS I debugged and figured it is happening because of first one but I did that because of I am doing server side rendering so first time when browser it is not available it looks for history. To avoid that I modified  `import { createBrowserHistory, createMemoryHistory } from "history"

let customHistory
if(process.env.BROWSER) {
  customHistory = createBrowserHistory()

} else {
  customHistory = createMemoryHistory()
}
export default customHistory
` and it is going to else part. Can you give me some pointer how this situation should be handled?

Comment: @cauchy You could probably check if `window` is defined for the module to determine whether to create a browser or memory history.

Comment: May I ask what does ` import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'` does? I see you are importing from the history file and you are on history file.

Comment: @UnityHour the absolute import of "history" is importing from the history package (http://npmjs.com/package/history), while the local module "history.js" is for your local history instance.

Comment: The only correct answer is below: import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

Comment: update to avoid deprecations - `import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history/createBrowserHistory';`

Comment: The history.js module may be a little more explicit by writing it this way:

```import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';```

```const history = createBrowserHistory()```


```export default history```

Comment: That's exactly what i'm doing but still not working,
the URL changes but the components don't update, i always get the 404 component i don't know why.

Comment: @HassanAzzam You are probably using react-router V5, and this answer works for V4, not V5. I have right now the same challenge, and am looking everywhere, but unable to make it work. history.push outside of component works, but clicks on the Link don’t anymore.

Comment: how to to do this with browserrouter and useHistory() hook, outside component?

Comment: @HassanAzzam use history@4.x.x for react router V4 and V5 to resolve your issue.

Comment: @HassanAzzam, are you wrapping your routes in `<Switch>`? The `location` object is structured differently when using `createBrowserHistory` (if you do console.log(location), you'll see it return {action: "PUSH", location: {...}}}) - maybe that's throwing off the Swtich?

Comment: Remember to use `Router` not `BrowserRouter`. As other people have commented.

Answer (score 80):

This works!
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    this.props.history;
  }
}

withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Comment: as long as you are in a component. I am not in a component

Comment: Thank you, this is the easiest and most straightforward way to link to another route from a component. I would just add that you need to do `this.props.history.push('/some_route');` in order for it to work.

Comment: @storm_buster `const Component = props => {... // stuff}` and `export default withRouter(Component)` works for me on a stateless component

Answer (score 15):

Basing on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121109/7838249) if you need history object only in order to navigate to other component:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: WRONG, you are  within a component. see // some-other-file.js from the accepted answer

Comment: useHistory (and React Hooks) is much nicer/cleaner than the accepted answer

Answer (score 13):

Similiary to accepted answer what you could do is use `react` and `react-router` itself to provide you `history` object which you can scope in a file and then export.

**history.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

// variable which will point to react-router history
let globalHistory = null;

// component which we will mount on top of the app
class Spy extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    globalHistory = props.history; 
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    globalHistory = this.props.history;
  }

  render(){
    return null;
  }
}

export const GlobalHistory = withRouter(Spy);

// export react-router history
export default function getHistory() {    
  return globalHistory;
}
```

You later then import Component and mount to initialize history variable:

```js
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { GlobalHistory } from './history';

function render() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <GlobalHistory />
            //.....
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    document.getElementById('app'),
  );
}
```

And then you can just import in your app when it has been mounted:

```js
import getHistory from './history'; 

export const goToPage = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: GO_TO_SUCCESS_PAGE });
  getHistory().push('/success'); // at this point component probably has been mounted and we can safely get `history`
};
```

I even made and [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-global-history) that does just that.

Comment: As of reactjs 16.9, this solution will spit out a deprecation warning on componentWillMount and componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: @ian true, fixed that

Answer (score 6):

If you are using redux and redux-thunk the best solution will be using [react-router-redux](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux)

```
// then, in redux actions for example
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

dispatch(push('/some/path'))
```

> It's important to see the docs to do some configurations.

Comment: I came here hoping to find this exact solution, thank you

Answer (score -2):

In the specific case of `react-router`, using [`context`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) is a valid case scenario, e.g.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  props: PropsType;

  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };

  render () {
    this.context.router;
  }
}
```

You can access an instance of the history via the router context, e.g. `this.context.router.history`.

Comment: The question specifically is asking about when outside of a component so this.context is not available as an option:
> "I know that I could use, the hoc withRouter, react context, or event router props when you are in a Component. but it is not the case for me."