# Programatically go to route with react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So, Im trying to go to the route /forecast that i have defined among my routes. When trying to reach it with a link like this:

```
<Link to="/forecast">Test</Link>
```

Its working. But now Im trying to reach it programatically, after a button press, and Im having trouble understanding what to do in v4 of react-router. Ive tried this:

```
history.push('/forecast');
```

Which is what i gathered from the official documentation. But its not working, what am i supposed to do when trying to reach a route inside a function?

Comment: Assuming the function is not inside a component used on <Route>, this has already been answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672842/how-to-get-history-on-react-router-v4

Comment: If your function is inside a component used in a <Route>, then the history object will be passed as properties to the component. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/Route-props

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but when Im trying to go to a location according to how I interpret the docs 

    this.props.history.push('/forecast');

it says that history is undefined...

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve