# Adding query parameters on form submission - React router 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The desired effect when submitting a form using React router 4 is to append the search query to the end of the URL.

My current setup will send an API request on form submission, and then render the results in the render method.

Without using Links or Redirects, is there a way to add the query onto the URL, maybe from within the form submission method?

Comment: You could use the `history` object in your submission function. Check out if this previous question to see if it's what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672842/how-to-get-history-on-react-router-v4

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically push the queries to the url like

```
this.props.router.push({
  pathname: '/yourRoute',
  query: { someQuery: 'value' }
})
```

Connect your Component with `witRouter` to be able to use the `router prop`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

....


export default withRouter(App);
```