# How React router hashHistory goBack function works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, history, browser-history

I am using `React-router 3.2.0` so I have a button in the application on which I called goBack function of hashHistory as below

```
Router.hashHistory.goBack();
```

I works fine but I need to add some condition before it called. So my problem is like if I move between 3 links

1. Home
2. Dashboard
3. Settings

Initially it will be on `Home` then I  moved to `Dashboard` then `Settings`. Now I clicked on button on which I called `goBack()` function at that time current history location is `Settings` it moved to `Dashboard` then `Home` after reaching at `Home` there is no such history locations exist.

So this is I need to check is there any history location still exist or not. Something like

```
if(/*history exist*/){
 call goBack();
} else {
 //do my stuff
}
```

Is there any way to do that in react-router 3.2.0 version ?

Comment: Maybe you can find here your answer ;) https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/408

Answer (score 0):

The `history` object in `react-router` has a [`length` property indicating how many entries are in the stack](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#properties).

```
if (history.length !== 0) {
 goBack();
} else {
 // do my stuff
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about window.history or any History object available in the react-router ?

Comment: @KushalJain The history object available in react-router.

Comment: I tried like import {History} from 'react-router'; then console.log(History) it occurs undefined.

Comment: @KushalJain The `history` object is not exported from `react-router` directly, but you can get it [like described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672842/how-to-get-history-on-react-router-v4).