# React Router Question: why history.push changes url but doesn't update component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, history.js

Below is a sample code that renders two buttons (home and about) and two page component (also Home and About). Upon clicking each button, the buttons would call `history.push` to go to the respective page and should render the component.

However, what I notice is that when a button is clicked, the url changes but the component doesn't show up. I manage to get this fixed by passing the `{ forceRefresh: true }` property when creating browser history like this `const history = createBrowserHistory({ forceRefresh: true });` Still, I don't quite understand why this occur and why forceRefresh solves the problem and would appreciate any explanation.

That reason I didn't use the `<Link>` component to wrap around the button is because I want to call a function to execute something before redirecting when the button is clicked. If there is another way to do this, I would love to know from the community. Thanks.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const MyApp = () => {
    const history = createBrowserHistory();
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <button onClick={() => history.push('/')}>Home</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button onClick={() => history.push('/about')}>About</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/'>
                        <Home />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path='/about'>
                        <About />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
};
```

```js
function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Home</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

function About() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>About</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Here is the code sandbox I created so you can run the code as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-bush-f3w08?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: use `Link` from react-router-dom`

Answer (score 3):

This is because of this line:

`const history = createBrowserHistory();`

You are instantiating a `history` object which will be used by `Router` to keep track of the routing history. This is something used under the hood by `Router` and you shouldn't need to worry about it.

What you're doing wrong is to think that the `history` variable you declared there (use by `Router`) is the same used to navigate through the app. It's not.

You should use this `history` to navigate:

`import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'`

Usage:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyApp = () => {
    const historyInstance = createBrowserHistory();

    const history = useHistory();

    return (
        <Router history={historyInstance}>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <button onClick={() => history.push('/')}>Home</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button onClick={() => history.push('/about')}>About</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/'>
                        <Home />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path='/about'>
                        <About />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
};
```

And with that, everything should work

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it makes sense and works like charm. Can you also use a useHistory hook inside a react class component instead of a functional component?

Comment: For those that want to access history inside a react class component, here is what I found that solves it: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672842/how-to-get-history-on-react-router-v4)