# props.history.push() not working in metronic theme

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, metronic

After login I am not redirecting to my users page I am using react metronic theme.
I think something is wrong with props.history.push()
Here what I have done so far.

Main component is below:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MetronicI18nProvider>
    <MetronicLayoutProvider>
      <MetronicSubheaderProvider>
        <MetronicSplashScreenProvider>
          <ToastContainer/>
          <App store={store} persistor={persistor} />
        </MetronicSplashScreenProvider>
      </MetronicSubheaderProvider>
    </MetronicLayoutProvider>
  </MetronicI18nProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App component:

```
export default function App({ store, persistor }) {
  return (
    /* Provide Redux store */
    <Provider store={store}>
      {/* Asynchronously persist redux stores and show `SplashScreen` while it's loading. */}
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={<LayoutSplashScreen />}>
        {/* Add high level `Suspense` in case if was not handled inside the React tree. */}
        <React.Suspense fallback={<LayoutSplashScreen />}>
          {/* Override `basename` (e.g: `homepage` in `package.json`) */}
          <BrowserRouter>
            {/*This library only returns the location that has been active before the recent location change in the current window lifetime.*/}
            <MaterialThemeProvider>
              {/* Provide `react-intl` context synchronized with Redux state.  */}
              <I18nProvider>
                {/* Render routes with provided `Layout`. */}
                <Routes />
              </I18nProvider>
            </MaterialThemeProvider>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </React.Suspense>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

This is my routers component

```
   <Switch>
            {getToken()==null? (
                <Route>
                    <AuthPage/>
                </Route>
            ) : (
                <Redirect from="/auth" to="/"/>
            )}

            <Route path="/error" component={ErrorsPage}/>

            {getToken()==null ? (
                <Redirect to="/auth/login"/>
            ) : (
                <Layout>
                    <BasePage/>
                </Layout>
            )}
        </Switch>
```

this is my base component

```
export default function BasePage() {
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<LayoutSplashScreen/>}>
            <Switch>
                <Redirect exact from="/" to="/allUsers"/>
                <ContentRoute path="/allUsers" component={AllUsers}/>
                <Redirect to="error/error-v1"/>
            </Switch>
        </Suspense>
    );
}
```

this is action which I fire after sign In button

```
 props.onLogin(values).then((res) => {
            toast.success('Login Successfull')
            props.history.push('/allUsers')
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('error', err)
            toast.error('Login failed')
        })
```

and I have same AuthPage component.

api is fired success fully, token is saved successfully and toaster is shown 'Login successful'. But I am not redirecting to my desired page.
But if I refresh then I am redirected to home page.

Can anyone help me with this

** history.push is working in `/allUsers` route. But not working in Login component

Update: I think I found what I am doing wrong.
I don't need to perform any history.push() action when I will save token(which is I am doing in my onLogin action) it should automatic redirect to AllUsers Page.
I changed my approach to as below and now it is working.

```
  const {isAuthorized} = useSelector(
        ({mainAuth}) => ({
            isAuthorized: mainAuth.user != null,
        }),
        shallowEqual
    );

replaced getToken with isAuthorized
```

But history.push() not working here is still mystery.

Comment: If no state persistence is needed you could also use `window.location.href = '/allUsers'` to redirect

Comment: Yes that will work but I want to know what is wrong with above code

Comment: If you can post a reproducible demo on codesandbox or share a github repository I can look at it, but there's not enough code here to figure out what's going on.

Comment: are you using customHistory?

Comment: were you able to find solution!?

Comment: No, Not able to find solution. But If I use forceRefresh then it is working, but it causes page refresh which isn't correct

Comment: I am curious why you have two conditional blocks in triggering on getToken() == null. I am probably missing something...

Comment: I am using react metronic theme so code was already set up like this

Answer (score 1):

Please use history package version as v4.9.0 for react-router v5.2.0

Working example
https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-dan-z3725

Originally answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64623542/1723410

Comment: I am using react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case you are not getting history reference in props. You can try these two solutions. `withRouter` from `react-router` & `useHistory` from `react-router-dom`.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'; 
componentName(){
   const { match, location, history } = this.props
    history.push('Your Page')
}
export default withRouter(componentName);

OR

import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

component(){
    const history = useHistory();
    history.push('Your Page')
}
```

Comment: I am getting history in props. but history.push not working

Comment: The code is not enough to understand what's going wrong. If possible share the Github repository so we can debug it.

Comment: @AbhishekYadav Have you tried both useHistory  & withRouter ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export someclass/ReactComponent{
.
.
.
const history = useHistory();

 props.onLogin(values).then((res) => {
            toast.success('Login Successfull')
            history.push('/allUsers')
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('error', err)
            toast.error('Login failed')
        })
}
}
```

Or refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672842/how-to-get-history-on-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have been able to reproduce your issue [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-sunset-bcilj?file=/src/App.js) but not sure yet about solution. But my while guess is that your root most Switch doesn't get triggered when you do history.push, so those expressions with getToken are not evaluated and thats why we are not redirected anywhere.

If I have time later to play around more, I might update this answer.