# React site navigating without reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

Need the ability to navigate without page reload.

For example from some place in code by clicking button or link

```
export default class Test1 extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    onClick() {
        this.props.history.push('/my-path')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <a className={this.props.className} onClick={this.onClick}>{this.props.children}</a>
            <input type="button" onClick={this.onCLick} value="halo2"/>
        );
    }

}
```

but this.props.history is undefined.

Things like

```
export default withRouter(Test1);
```

produce an error

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(Test1) /> outside a <Router>
```

Most positive effect reached with creating additional history class like here [How to get history on react-router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672842/how-to-get-history-on-react-router-v4)

But it only change URL without actually moving to that location(does not render and does not executes expected events).

**UPDATE 1**

even tried push history to global variable

```
class DebugRouter extends BrowserRouter {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        App.history = this.history;
```

and than

```
App.history.push('/my path');
```

It also only change URL. No changes to the page and events

Comment: Try changing `import {Route, Switch} from "react-router";` to `import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";`

Comment: @PulsaraSandeepa it is import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch,} from "react-router-dom"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use for that `Link` from `'react-router-dom'`.

So you can just change `<a>` to `<Link to='/path'>Text</Link>`

Also make sure that your whole app is inside of provider `<BrowserRouter>` otherwise none of it will work.

Here is usefull link how to use it: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: yep... already mentioned that place wanted to work is outside the router...