# TypeError: props.history.listen is not a function. I am using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is this showing? I am using ReacJS and I can not see what is wrong.

**My history.js:**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

export default createBrowserHistory
```

**My App.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'

import Routes from './routes'
import history from './history'

import './styles/global.scss'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router history={history}>
        <Routes/>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672842/how-to-get-history-on-react-router-v4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get history on react-router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672842/how-to-get-history-on-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 3):

You need to invoke `createBrowserHistory` and then export it. Try changing the line to:

```
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to import Router component,the root router component which takes history as a prop.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
```

and as `Sajib Khan` said, you should also call the `createBrowserHistory` then use it as history prop.